# updating label variables from a running timer

Tags: swift, timer, label

I'm trying to create a counter that does simple math when the timer reaches zero. I have my timer working somewhat correctly, and the labels displaying the original variables, but they are not updating as the timer hits "zero". Where am I going wrong in my code?

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var goldCounter: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var turnCounter: UILabel!

    var seconds = 15
    var timer = Timer()
    var gold = 1000
    var turns = 1



    func updatelabels () {
    goldCounter.text = String(gold)
    turnCounter.text = String(turns) }




    func runTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer),userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func updateTimer() {
        seconds -= 1
        timerLabel.text = String(seconds)
        if seconds == 0 {
            seconds = 15}
        }


    func increaseGold () {
        if seconds == 1 {
            gold = gold + 1000
            turns = turns + 1
        }}

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.runTimer()
        goldCounter.text = String(gold)
        turnCounter.text = String(turns)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    func increaseGold () {
        if seconds == 1 {
            gold = gold + 1000
            turns = turns + 1
        }}
   func updatelabels () {
        goldCounter.text = String(gold)
        turnCounter.text = String(turns) }

    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You have two `increaseGold` functions that are defined inside of other functions, and then never called. Do you want the timer to loop continuously, and the gold to increase by 1000 every 15 seconds?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I would like to happen. I put the second function in there because I thought i had placed the first one in a wrong area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is that you aren't calling `updateLabels` to update your labels.

I would suggest using property observers (`didSet`) to set your labels as the values change instead of relying on a separate function to change them.

Also, you need to call `increaseGold` in your timer handler:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var goldCounter: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var turnCounter: UILabel!

    var seconds = 15 {
        didSet {
            timerLabel.text = String(seconds)
        }
    }

    var timer = Timer()

    var gold = 1000 {
        didSet {
            goldCounter.text = String(gold)
        }
    }

    var turns = 1 {
        didSet {
            turnCounter.text = String(turns)
        }
    }

    func runTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer),userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func updateTimer() {
        seconds -= 1
        if seconds == 0 {
            seconds = 15
        }
        increaseGold()
    }

    func increaseGold () {
        if seconds == 1 {
            gold = gold + 1000
            turns = turns + 1
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        seconds = 15
        gold = 1000
        turns = 1
        self.runTimer()
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you so much for this. Easily explains what I was doing wrong and how to correctly do it in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think when you added `let`, your problem is gone. Delete `var timer = Timer()`. It is not neccessary

```
func runTimer() {
    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer),userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```